# sorting arrays only sorts a few

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I`ve been trying to bubble sort an array in java for some time now, but every time it just does a few and then it follows the array list.

```
public void mysort() {
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    int randomArray[] = new int[20];

    for (int j = 0; j <= 19; j++) {
        randomArray[j] = randomNumbers.nextInt(200 + 1);
        for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
            if (randomArray[k - 1] < randomArray[k]) {
                int hjelp = randomArray[k - 1];
                randomArray[k - 1] = randomArray[k];
                randomArray[k] = hjelp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
    }
}
```

How do I make my bubble sort work properly?

Comment: where is your bubble sort?

Comment: This question does not contain an actual sort operation.

Comment: You're initializing the array and running the sorting algorithm 20 times, I am pretty sure that is not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should populate the array first, and THEN call the sort. You're "sorting" the array 20 times, while it's still incomplete.

```
public void mysort() {
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    int randomArray[] = new int[20];

    for (int j = 0; j < randomArray.length; j++) {
        randomArray[j] = randomNumbers.nextInt(200) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < randomArray.length; k++) {
            if (randomArray[k - 1] < randomArray[k]) {
                int hjelp = randomArray[k - 1];
                randomArray[k - 1] = randomArray[k];
                randomArray[k] = hjelp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow i have neve seen a bubble sort of complexcity N. In fact I have never seen any sort with complexity N. Did you try your code ?

Comment: @StackFlowed I shouldn't have given him the benefit of doubt, huh. It's O(n^2)... right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate array first.
You are trying to populate and sort at the same time.

Populate :

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 19; j++ ){
        randomArray[j] = randomNumbers.nextInt(200+1);
}
```

Sort :

BubleSort();

Answer (score 1):

You code should have been like this :

```
Random randomNumbers = new Random();
int randomArray[] = new int[20];
for (int j = 0; j <= 19; j++) {
    randomArray[j] = randomNumbers.nextInt(200 + 1);
}
for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
        if (randomArray[k - 1] < randomArray[k]) {
            int hjelp = randomArray[k - 1];
            randomArray[k - 1] = randomArray[k];
            randomArray[k] = hjelp;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
    System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
}
```

Note you are doing this in descending order. if you want to do it in ascending order change

```
if (randomArray[k - 1] < randomArray[k])
```

to

```
if (randomArray[k - 1] > randomArray[k])
```